# How to render conditional HTML elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

What is wrong with the following code? I have tried many options given in the [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e/).

```
  { 
      !hideCurrentLocation && (
        {currentLocation?.city}
        {currentLocation?.city && ', '}
        {currentLocation?.country_code2}
      )
  }
```

It is giving error on line `{currentLocation?.city}` that a comma is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many brackets. Also, if you're trying to render a "city, countrycode" you need to return a single node for valid JSX. I suggest dumping the city and country code into an array and joining them into a single string.

```
{!hideCurrentLocation && (
  <>
    {[currentLocation?.city, currentLocation?.country_code2]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join(", ")}
  </>
)}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, there is no error now. But it is not printing city and country code when !hideCurrentLocation == true. Both are strings but getting converted into boolean.

Comment: @UmairJameel Oops, meant to filter the array, sorry. the `.filter(Boolean)` will filter out falsey values, leaving only the defined `city` or `country_code2` left to join together.